# Is there an OS selector for GPT style partitioned hard drives?

Tags: boot, gpt

I've installed Ubuntu on my external hard drive and whenever I want to boot that, I have to hit F12 and go into the settings and give priority to my USB over the Windows boot, so this process is a bit tiring when you want to work with both OSs(Although I use the Linux mostly), every time you have to change that setting and restart the system.

I searched this and found an [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/532742/how-can-i-make-my-computer-ask-me-which-os-i-want-to-load-while-booting) but it's a bit old and is primarily talking about MBR style partitioned hard drives while all my drives are GPT, so what can I do? Is there a better(faster and maybe more modern) way to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the partition table format, but everything to do with the computer's firmware type.

- If you use a BIOS system, it will always run the initial bootloader from sector 0 (the 'MBR'), even if it's a GPT disk which doesn't store partitions there.

  *(The BIOS itself doesn't care about partitions – it just needs the boot code. Understanding partitions is the job of whatever boot code was installed.)*
- If you use an UEFI system, it will always read boot entries from NVRAM and will run the selected bootloader from the EFI system partition.

  *(The UEFI specification defines an 'EFI system partition' for **both** GPT and MBR.)*

Only the specifics of installing the chosen bootloader may change (e.g. if you're installing GRUB2 for BIOS, it needs additional GPT-specific preparation).

So the answer you found remains the same – make one bootloader *chainload* into the other. Your Ubuntu already uses GRUB2, so adding Windows (even from another disk) to it should be quite possible.

However: If you use an UEFI system with "CSM (BIOS compatibility)" mode active, and your operating systems were installed in different modes (e.g. Windows installed in UEFI mode but Ubuntu installed in BIOS mode), then you *probably cannot* use the same custom boot manager to handle both.

---

But in any case, the first thing I'd do is **find out whether the firmware has its own boot menu** separate from the settings screen. Practically all recent firmwares have such a menu: it might be accessible by pressing (or holding) <kbd>Esc</kbd>, or <kbd>F8</kbd>, or <kbd>F11</kbd>, or similar. (I've seen computers with this feature as far back as 2006.)

Because this boot menu is meant for making a *temporary* selection (won't permanently change the boot settings), it would give you the same "OS selector" feature without the need to configure a custom boot manager. The only difference is one extra key press.

Additionally, the firmware's built-in boot menu *does* work for mixed UEFI/BIOS systems – most of the time it will show both UEFI entries and BIOS devices in the same list.

Comment: Wow, thanks, your answer is complete! I'm almost sure that my windows 10 is using the UEFI system, but is there a way to know what is the mode of my Ubuntu system? Maybe a terminal command? If I've installed it in BIOS mode then NOTHING can be done!? I hope I've not done that! Also for holding the F8/F11/ESC keys, thanks, it's a really cool way, I hope I have it. I'm going to test all of them now.

Comment: Boot Ubuntu, then check whether `efibootmgr -v` shows boot entries and/or whether the `/sys/firmware/efi/efivars/` directory has items in it. If they're all empty, that indicates BIOS mode (although converting between the two is a 5-minute job anyway).

Comment: Oh wow, it works like a charm! For me it is holding the ESC button. I'm such an unaware person :) Also fortunately, the mode was UEFI itself and I don't need to change that. Thanks again.

Comment: @Narnia Don't beat yourself up :) You recognized your former limitation, read and understood this excellent answer and improved based on it. There are people here knowing much less than that, creating problems for themselves by insisting in "BIOS mode" where it isn't needed and not recommended and when answers like this would have helped them they, instead of trying to understand, antagonize those who are helping them. I had one of those just yesterday.